# Setting up event listener for parent component property

Tags: angular, event-listener, angular-components

### A little bit of background

I have a simple chat app made with Angular 2. My application, like most Angular 2 applications, start with an `AppComponent`, which uses `router-outlet` to render the child components based on routing.

In a `ChatComponent` I am injecting back the `AppComponent`.

```
constructor( @Inject(forwardRef(() => AppComponent)) app: AppComponent) { .. }
```

I do this because this `AppComponent` is also the gateway to the chat server. So no matter on what page you are, chats will always be received by the application.

The `AppComponent` class also has a `public usersOnline` array which is a list of all the current online users.

This is maybe not the most sexy way, but it does the trick for me. So far so good.

### My question

Whenever I navigate to my `ChatComponent`, how can I then setup some sort of event listener, so that this component can do certain things when the `AppComponent` updates the `usersOnline` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `usersOnline` to an observable (or specifically, a subject) and then in your `ChatComponent` do:

```
app.usersOnline$.subscribe(value => ({value handler code>});
```

or, if it is something you need in your template:

```
<div>Number of online users {(app.usersOnline$ | async).?length}</div>
```

In your `AppComponent` change the assignment from:

```
this.usersOnline = <some_value>;
```

to

```
this.usersOnline$.next(<some_value>);
```